# SEO developer relations and Site speed

Tags: seo, web-development

I am putting a presentation together on how SEO consultants and developers can work well together. I would really appreciate it if any developers that work regularly with SEO consultants especially on site speed issues can spare a couple on minutes to answer my questions

1. What is the most ridiculous site speed request you have ever been
   asked by an SEO?
2. If the request would have impacted the site negatively what would
   the impact have been?
3. What do you wish SEO's would think about before making requests
4. How could they better present recommendations
5. Do you use WebP for images? if not why
6. What is the implication of the request - remove legacy code, how difficult is this to implement

Many thanks in advance,

Kind regards